# Web scraping the required content from a url link in R

Tags: html, r, xml, web-scraping, rvest

I am very new to web scraping and attempting to scrape the required content from a link.

This is the actual URL for the above picture: `https://ssb.bannerprod.memphis.edu/prod/bwckschd.p_get_crse_unsec`

I want the output to be looked like below:

```
Sections Found                                    Instructors              email id
Academic Strategies - 10582 - ACAD 1100 - 001    Beverly McPhail  
Academic Strategies - 10586 - ACAD 1100 - 002    Emily K Mann      
Academic Strategies - 10590 - ACAD 1100 - 005    Christopher D Bourque
```

I see the `email id` is not visible, I can only see the symbol. I saw about `rvest` package in R and started using like below, but I see an Error:

```
library(rvest)
url <- read_html("https://ssb.bannerprod.memphis.edu/prod/bwckschd.p_get_crse_unsec")

Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 500.
```

To go the data which is in the picture:

```
In this link `https://ssb.bannerprod.memphis.edu/prod/bwckschd.p_disp_dyn_sched` 
Select by term -> Spring Term 2021 (view only) -> Submit
Subject -> select ACAD Academics -> scroll down and click Class Search
```

This will bring you to the link `https://ssb.bannerprod.memphis.edu/prod/bwckschd.p_get_crse_unsec`

May I know how to this type of scraping in R? thanq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is tricky. The web page is only served once the server receives a POST request with the appropriate form, so this is not a simple case of sending a normal GET request to a url like `read_html` does. You need to construct the POST request "by hand" to get the page you want.

```r
library(rvest)
#> Loading required package: xml2

url   <- "https://ssb.bannerprod.memphis.edu/prod/bwckschd.p_get_crse_unsec"

query <- list(term_in = "202110", sel_subj = "dummy", sel_day = "dummy",
              sel_schd = "dummy", sel_insm = "dummy", sel_camp = "dummy",
              sel_levl = "dummy", sel_sess = "dummy", sel_instr = "dummy",
              sel_ptrm = "dummy", sel_attr = "dummy", sel_subj = "ACAD",
              sel_crse = "",      sel_title = "",     sel_insm = "%",
              sel_from_cred = "", sel_to_cred = "",   sel_camp = "%",
              sel_levl = "%",     sel_ptrm = "%",     sel_instr = "%",
              sel_attr = "%",     begin_hh =  "0",    begin_mi = "0",
              begin_ap = "a",     end_hh = "0",       end_mi = "0",
              end_ap = "a")

html <- read_html(httr::POST(url, body = query))
```

Once you have the html, you can use xpath to get the nodes you want to scrape:

```
classes <- html %>% html_nodes(xpath = "//th/a") %>% html_text()

instructor_nodes <- html %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath = "//td[@class='dddefault']/a[contains(@href, 'mailto')]")
  
instructors <- html_attr(instructor_nodes, "target") 

emails <- html_attr(instructor_nodes, "href") 

df <- data.frame(classes, instructors, emails)

df
#>                                         classes            instructors
#> 1 Academic Strategies - 10582 - ACAD 1100 - 001        Beverly McPhail
#> 2 Academic Strategies - 10586 - ACAD 1100 - 002          Emily K. Mann
#> 3 Academic Strategies - 10590 - ACAD 1100 - 005 Christopher D. Bourque
#>                        emails
#> 1 mailto:blahblah@memphis.edu
#> 2   mailto:blahbl@memphis.edu
#> 3 mailto:blahblah@memphis.edu
```

Note I have obviously obscured the e-mail addresses of the individuals involved rather than posting them on a public web page without their consent.